# API key with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to run my rally scripts from a confluence wiki. Based on process I have to do this via wiki markup, so there is no `iframe` call to attach the key to the html request. Is there a way to embed the key in the JavaScript so that it's incorporated within the HTML body/Rally calls?

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the HTML macro?

https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-put-an-iframe-into-confluence-598837531.html

If so you should be able to follow the directions in the Embedding Apps guide: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

Comment: Right now the admin is targeting my to use Wiki Markup and embed the HTML (from the rally_app_builder) there vs the iframe call.   Is there any way to do it that way?  Thanks! Mark

Comment: There is not.  Sort of by design.  We didn't want to support embedding api keys in app code because we didn't want them showing up in github repositories accidentally...